# Make RelativeLayout checkable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I try to write my own `CheckBox` using `RelativeLayout` with `TextView` and `FrameLayout` (with selector on background) inside.

I have `setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true)` for `FrameLayout` that it take checkable status from parent, but why make `RelativeLayout` checkable I don't know.

```
public class MyCheckbox extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener, Checkable
{
private static final int ID_CHECKBOX = -1234411;
private static final int ID_TEXTVIEW = -1234412;
private static final int ID_PARENT = -1234413;

private TextView textView;
private FrameLayout checkBox;
private boolean isChecked;

public MyCheckbox(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public MyCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutParams lp;

    setId(ID_PARENT);
    setOnClickListener(this);

    // checkBox
    checkBox = new FrameLayout(context);
    checkBox.setId(ID_CHECKBOX);
    checkBox.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);

    // textView
    textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setId(ID_TEXTVIEW);
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);


    boolean checkboxToRight = false;

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaptrixCheckbox);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.getIndexCount(); i++)
    {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr)
        {
            case R.styleable.MyCheckbox_checkboxToRight:
                checkboxToRight = a.getBoolean(attr, false);
                break;

            case R.styleable.MyCheckbox_checkMark:
                checkBox.setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(attr));
                break;

            case R.styleable.MyCheckbox_text:
                textView.setText(a.getText(attr));
                break;
        }
    }
    a.recycle();

    if (checkboxToRight)
    {
        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        lp.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lp.setMargins(margins, 0, margins, 0);
        addView(checkBox, lp);

        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lp.addRule(LEFT_OF, ID_CHECKBOX);
        addView(textView, lp);
    }
    else
    {
        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lp.setMargins(margins, 0, margins, 0);
        addView(checkBox, lp);

        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lp.addRule(RIGHT_OF, ID_CHECKBOX);
        addView(textView, lp);
    }

    refreshDrawableState();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == ID_PARENT || id == ID_TEXTVIEW) toggle();
}

public boolean isChecked()
{
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean chacked)
{
    isChecked = chacked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

@Override
public void toggle()
{
    isChecked = !isChecked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just need override method:

```
private static final int[] STATE_CHECKABLE = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
{
    int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (isChecked) mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_CHECKABLE);
    return drawableState;
}
```

Now all works.

Comment: Can you post your layout XML? I'm having problems too. Did you set android:clickable="true" in the layout by any chance?

Answer (score 9):

There seem to be two UI patterns for multi-select lists in Holo (in the context of ActionMode): using checkboxes or highlighting.

If all you need is highlighting, you can use this simpler method:

Make your list item layout use for the root a class like this one:

```
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {
private static final int[] STATE_CHECKABLE = {R.attr.state_pressed};
boolean checked = false;

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!checked);
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (checked) mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_CHECKABLE);

    return drawableState;
}
}
```

and make sure the root element in your list item layout uses

```
android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"
```

I know this is not really an answer to your question (you wanted an actual checkbox), but I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

The ListView uses the Checkable interface to determine whether it can rely on the list item element to display the checkable state or if it should try to display it itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @Pierre-Luc! I have wasted so much time on this in the last couple of days and your implementation was a great starting point. I also didn't want a checkbox but needed to implement checkable.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc, you are a legend sir. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/) to implement a checkable RelativeLayout but was missing refreshDrawableState(). My ListView items had to be touched twice before the item became selected (highlighted).

Comment: Sure it's supposed to be "R.attr.state_pressed" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper that's what seems to work, as the purpose of this implementation is to mimic a pressed state when the list item is selected.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPaour But its name is "checkable" and the question is about checkable...

Comment: Sorry… I meant "mimic a pressed state when the list item is checked" (but without a checkbox). In the main body of my answer, I do note that this may not answer the question.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It should be `android.R.attr.state_pressed`, but otherwise it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Nik's answer is partially right for me, you need added **android.R.attr.state_checkable** into the STATE_CHECKABLE array, and set the corresponding lenth (2), or else it fails to work.

```
private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_checkable};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
{
    int[] result = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + CHECKED_STATE_SET.length);
    if(mChecked) mergeDrawableStates(result, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29

```
public MyCheckbox(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
    this.setClickable(true);
}

public MyCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setClickable(true);
//......
}
```

Comment: not clickable! I need make my view checkable I already solve my question.