# Contextual Action Bar and Checkbox problems

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, contextual-action-bar

So I got as far to as this, please keep in mind that the listView is dynamic as it is called from an API.

- An Adapter for the ListView.
- Contextual ActionBar Implementation.

What is now needed.

- For the Contextual ActionBar and CheckBox items to sync (like if all the icons are unchecked, the action bar is to be destroyed)

What I tried:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder vh;

            if(convertView == null){
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.projectlist_frame, null);
                vh.projectTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.projecttitle);
                vh.projectSector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.projectsector);
                vh.cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                convertView.setTag(vh);

            } else{
                vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            vh.projectTitle.setText(mData.get(position).get("title").toString());
            vh.projectSector.setText(mData.get(position).get("sector").toString());


            vh.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(isChecked){
                            if(mMode==null){
                                mMode = startActionMode(mActionCallBack);
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(mMode!=null){
                            mMode.finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView projectTitle, projectSector;
            CheckBox cb;
        }
    }
```

For in Contextuals ActionBar

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                list.setItemChecked(i, false);

            if (mode == mMode) {
                mMode = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mode.setTitle("Options");
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_add_project, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long[] selected = list.getCheckedItemIds();
            if (selected.length > 0) {
                for (long id: selected) {
                    // Do something with the selected item
                }
            }
            mode.finish();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Can somebody please help me track the onCheck events and coordinate its actions with contextual actionBar.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549271/highlight-custom-listview-item-when-long-click/18549314#18549314 if it helps