# Wrong item selected on Listview onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, onitemclick

Facing a very weird issue. I have a `listview` with `checkbox` on every item, when i click on the first item of the `listview` it is being selected, but along with this item, **the last item of the listview is also being selected!** when i scroll the listview. Without scroll it works perfect.

Also when i am selecting the last item, first item is being selected along with it after scrolling. Remind, all other items between these first and last are working correctly. And the funny part is, after selecting the first or last item, **if i don't scroll the `listview` for 2-3 seconds it works perfectly then**.So i am expecting this may be a problem of view rendering or somewhat. Can somebody point me what the hell is going on here..

```
Cursor cursor = queryDatabase();

    // The desired columns to be bound
      String[] columns = new String[] {               
        DataBaseHelper.ROW_PROFILE_NAME,
        DataBaseHelper.ROW_PROFILE_TYPE,
        DataBaseHelper.ROW_ID
      };

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.profileName,
        R.id.profileStatus
      };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.profile_listview_delete_item, 
        cursor, 
        columns, 
        to,
        0);

      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profile_listview_delete_main);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            CheckBox cb;                

            Cursor c = mAdapter.getCursor();
            String prodile_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.ROW_ID));

            cb = (CheckBox)arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            cb.toggle();

            if(cb.isChecked())
            {                   
                profileStack.add(prodile_id);                   
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(profileStack), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                counter++;              
            }
            else if(!cb.isChecked())
            {
                profileStack.remove(prodile_id);                    
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(profileStack), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                counter--;                  
            }               
            countSelectedItem.setText(String.valueOf(counter)+" items selected");

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you Please post your Adapter Class I Think this is problem of View Holder Pattern?

Comment: @Rajesh,i am using SimpleCursorAdapter as you can see the code above.

Comment: Your way of code is wrong. You have to use custom adapter with viewholder class, From that adapter while change the value of your checkbox you have to change value of a field from your adapter regards this checkbox. After while clicking listview get the position and get the values from your adapter.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844210/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-a-listview-populated-from-arraylist-in-android/25844671#25844671.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android listview duplicates the item on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398529/android-listview-duplicates-the-item-on-scroll)

Comment: @Shruti, that is not the duplicate that you mentioned. Do you check my code? i used notifyDataSetChanged() there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom `Adapter` (and a model class it is `optional`. Here `TemaRescatado` is a model class in snippet) for that. In `getView(...)` you have to use [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) try to use [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

- [Tutorial on listview with check box](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

**code snippet**

```
viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
         boolean isChecked) {
         TemaRescatado element = (TemaRescatado) viewHolder.checkbox
                  .getTag();
         element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

         }
      });
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to correct the problem with current code? Because i told all other items are working good.

Comment: I'm not sure but, it is not possible it is better to custom adapter because it will optimize your code and implementing `ViewHolder` pattern `ListView's` scroll will be *smooth*

Comment: u can try with `mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()` after `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: as @kaushik suggested...use viewholder else you will get undesired result

Comment: @kaushik, notifyDataSetInvalidated() not works either, i know possibly ViewHolder may solve this problem, but it will be a long task to change the code of an end app!

Comment: @ridoy : just follow that tutorial and you just need hardly half an hour to implement it

Answer (score 1):

You should get the cursor from AdapterView which is passed as argument to the onItemClick method.

Change the code.

```
Cursor c = mAdapter.getCursor();
```

to

```
Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Nope, it not changes the situation.

Comment: Updated my answer check this and let me know it si working ot not.

Comment: nope it is not working. Still the same thing, check 1st item and then scroll through, seen the last item also selected! But check 1st item, wait 2 seconds, scroll through and then seen it works good! weird!

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because `ListView`'s recycling. It re uses the first visible  `View`s as soon as it is not visible to show next data of the adapter.Therefore when you check and checkbox with respect to a data in the `List`'s position. it will remain same as you left it. So My solution to this issue is :

in your adapter's `getView()`

put a simple if-else statement to check if the checkbox should be checked or not like this:

```
// note that this is a pseudo code
if(ID exist in profileStack){
//set checkBox
}
else{
//set checkBox
}
```