# Single & Multiple Items Select in listview using listadapter in listactivity

Tags: android, listview

I am using customized listview with listadaper in listactivity.I want to add the option for single & multiple items selecting in listview.I searched about this but all are using check box with adapter class.I dont have any adapter class in my app.I am using listactivity with no adapter class.So how can i get the view of checkbox for single /multiple select?

***My adapter:***

```
ListAdapter   adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), entriesList,R.layout.new_todo_singleentry, new String[] 
{"``id","time","date","message","status"},new int[] { R.id.todo_id,R.id.todo_time,R.id.todo_date,R.id.todo_entry});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView Multiselection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378414/listview-multiselection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549271/highlight-custom-listview-item-when-long-click

Comment: To get idea, check this [Single selection in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview/29030776#29030776)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an option to do this without a custom adapter class.
I would advice you to read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) and use the example in chapter 14 to create the functionality that you are looking for.