# selecting multiple rows of a listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I am struggling at the moment on how to select multiple rows of a listview. I ve seen some other questions here but the solutions look a bit vague and unclear.

So this is what I am thinking. I have the listview ref variable

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOISE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

What should I exactly do next to select multiple rows as well as saving their ids in an String array? Should I call any callback method like onItemClickListener(...). I tried this but it didn't work.

Any help would be really helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView Multiselection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378414/listview-multiselection)

Comment: Please google before posting here. this question has been asked a lot of times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378414/listview-multiselection. Write some code and come back when you have a specific question.