# How to make selected row to be stay selected in listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

> I am working with list view , when i select the row in list view it is selected its working fine. But i want the list row to be stay highlighted even when am selecting multiple row in listview.

**Giftafriend.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Giftafriend extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
ListView list;
String[] product;
String[] price;
int[] image;
TextView total;
TableLayout stk;
private Giftlist adapter;

ArrayList<Gift> arraylist = new ArrayList<Gift>();
ArrayList<Gift> selected = new ArrayList<Gift>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int amount=0;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_giftafriend, container, false);

    product = new String[]{"Hair", "MSpa", "Style", "Style",
            "Hair", "Spa", "Spa", "Style", "HaIR", "hAIR"};

    price = new String[]{"100", "200", "400", "150",
            "200", "320", "400", "150", "200", "150"};

    image = new int[]{R.drawable.coloring, R.drawable.style, R.drawable.spa, R.drawable.straitning, R.drawable.treatment,
            R.drawable.spa, R.drawable.straitning, R.drawable.treatment, R.drawable.coloring, R.drawable.style};

    // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
    total=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        Gift wp = new Gift(product[i], image[i], price[i]);
        arraylist.add(wp);
    }

    adapter = new Giftlist(getContext(), arraylist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | android.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.giftactionbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    return view;
}

private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

int amount=0;
public void showAdd(View view)
{
    int position = list.getPositionForView(view);
    Gift gift = adapter.getItem(position);
    amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(gift.getPrice());
    total.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}}
```

**Giftlist.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Giftlist extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
private int counter = 0;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private java.util.List<Gift> rest=null;
private int selectedPosition = 1;
private ArrayList<Gift> arraylist=new ArrayList<Gift>();
LinearLayout listrow;

public Giftlist(Context context,
                       java.util.List<Gift> rest) {
    mContext = context;
    this.rest = rest;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Gift>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(rest);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rest.size();
}

@Override
public Gift getItem(int position) {
    return rest.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view1;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view1 = new View(mContext);
        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.giftlist, null);

    } else {
        view1 = (View)view;
    }

    TextView product = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.product);
    final TextView price = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.price);
    ImageView dish = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.image);
    listrow=(LinearLayout) view1.findViewById(R.id.listrow);

    product.setText(rest.get(position).getProduct());
    price.setText(rest.get(position).getPrice());
    dish.setImageResource(rest.get(position).getImage());

     if (position == selectedPosition) {
         listrow.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
         listrow.setSelected(true);
     }
     else
         listrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    return view1;
}
public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
this.selectedPosition = position;
   }}
```

Comment: Am struct with this , need help for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference and store the position of the listview item which you want to save for multi selection.

Comment: Before saving i want to make my list row stay selected

Comment: you can use setOnSelectedItemListener for the listview when you want to select one or more. You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363872/3009487

Answer (score 0):

You set `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);` to your listView when you want to select multiple items and then `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);` when you want no selection.

see more here [Highlight custom listview item when long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549271/highlight-custom-listview-item-when-long-click) or here [Selecting multiple items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview)

edit:

You also need to set `background` to your `ListView` rows to a selector resource like `bg_list_item.xml`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected"
  android:state_checked="true" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/not_selected" />
```

This is just an overview, for full implementation, please refer to the links provided.