# Checkable GridView

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Hi I'm writhing a checkable gridView and its working. but not the way its intending (as usual)
everything works like i want except that there is a latency when the the checkbox being drawn.

the grid will become true but the image wont draw until i check another grid. same goes for unchecking with the false statement.

its probably something really easy and stupid but i feel Ive become a bit blind staring at it.
Many tanks.

```
   public class CheckableImageView extends ImageView implements Checkable {


    private boolean mChecked=false;

    public CheckableImageView(final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "toggle  "+mChecked,                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked == checked)
            return;
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();

    }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     if(mChecked) {
     Bitmap check = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
     getResources(), R.drawable.cecked);
     canvas.drawBitmap(check, 0,0, new Paint());

     }
     }
```

Adapter/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////7

```
             public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return randomList.size();
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        CheckableImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new CheckableImageView(context, null);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        } else {
            imageView = (CheckableImageView) convertView;


        }

        imageView.setImageResource(randomList.get(position));


        return imageView;
    }

}
```

OnItemClick/////////////////////////////////////////////

```
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {


              cv = (CheckableImageView) v;
              cv.toggle();
              cv.refreshDrawableState();

        }
    });
```

Comment: solved it by adding an invalidate statement on setChecked.
but if someone wants to comment on my noob coding please be my guest ,just makes me stronger :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on the Adapter when you change the data or information pertaining to it. That will cause the Grid to become invalidated and redraw based on what you have overridden in the getView() method of your Adapter.

Comment: i have set notifyDataDetChanged on the adapter but it doesn't do anything but adding invalidate on the checkable imageview works. is it the wrong way to go?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); should cause the views to be invalidated, so invalidating the one view that's clicked doesn't seem like a bad solution (if it works correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can chop off about half that code by using an anonymous class in your `ImageAdapter.getView`.

```
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext()) {
                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    super.onDraw(canvas);
                    if(((GridView)parent).isItemChecked(position)) {
                        //...
                    }
                }
            };
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A checkable requires to also override OnCreateDrawableState to realize the drawable needs to be changed and a redraw is required.

See [Make RelativeLayout checkable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775710/make-relativelayout-checkable)

Answer (score 0):

Call invalidate() on your imageview in onClicklistener after toggle. Works perfectly, just tried it.