# How to make a CardView have a clickable&checkable effect, and how to make it dark themed?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-cardview, android-design-library

### Background

Before CardView was introduced, I made some selectors on [**my app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) to mimic cards, and let the user also choose which theme to use for the app (some prefer a dark theme) :

[image]

### The problem

I wanted to make it look&work more natively, so I tried using CardView.

Sadly, I fail to understand how to set the CardView have a clickable&checkable effect (the native one of each platform, maybe with a different color), and also have the ability to set it a dark theme.

### The questions

1. How do I make a CardView have a clickable effect? On Lollipop it's a ripple effect. On previous ones it's full color changing within the boundaries of the CardView. I'd also like to customize the color of the clickable effect, and let it also be checkable.
2. How do I make a dark-theme CardView ?

Comment: In dark theme mode, you have to customize theme and specially shade/elevation color to show contrast in app UI

Comment: I got the clickable CardView functionality implemented recently using this answer as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475150/android-l-cardview-visual-touch-feedback/30192562#30192562

Comment: @DanielNugent Looks nice. Do you know what should be the cardCornerRadius and contentPadding standards? Is it possible to also make the cardView have a "checked" state?

Comment: I had to tweak those values in order to make it perfect, it will be different depending on your CardView layout.  I used a ListView of CardViews, it worked out nicely.  As for "selected" state, my solution there was a bit messy, but it works.  I resorted to manually "selecting" a CardView on long click, and then keep a reference to the selected View in order to make sure that it appeared selected even when there was cell re-use using the view-holder pattern.

Comment: @DanielNugent I succeed adding checkable state, using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775710/make-relativelayout-checkable , and add state_checked to the selector of card_foreground.xml  . However, because it's the foreground, it changes the content of the card, so if I choose a completely opaque color, it hides the entire content of the card.

Comment: i tried your app and i think you can help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886756/multi-select-cardview-in-listview) guy, i think he has a good question

Comment: @Mohamed Sure, I will help when it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the CardView.Dark style for the dark-theme CardView. You can also just use the colors as mentioned in the 11th and 12th comments of this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194497).

Answer (score 0):

This was requested on google at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194497

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This functionality is added.**

**Add dark theme for CardView**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

### Example:

Add below attribute to your cardview

```
style="@style/CardView.Dark"
```

### as shown here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cards"
        style="@style/CardView.Dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usersName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/others"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usersName"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Others"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The request was made by  me :)  But how do I use it ?

Comment: please check my updated answer. @androiddeveloper i have added example in it.

Comment: I've actually solved it a long time ago (and it's in my app), but maybe yours is better or more official. Where in your code do you deal with the states of the card (pressed, checked/selected,...) ?

Comment: i have tested and isPressed(); .isSelected(); are working.